# Dynamic Configuration Roots? Based on db call?

Tags: dependency-injection, architecture, inversion-of-control, ninject, dependency-inversion

I have an app that at startup knows just enough to pick a database and pull a configuration object.

It then executes on that configuration object, disposes a bunch of things, pulls another configuration object, executes on that, etc, in a loop.

Right now, I have a configuration root at the beginning of the app that configures everything it can.  But since it doesn't know everything until after the db call, all of the object branches after that point are hidden behind factories of factories, so they can handle whatever config happens to be in the config object.

My question is, is this normal?  It seems like the alternative would be to have two configuration roots, or two DI Containers.  One before, and one after the db call.

If I could do my DI root after the db call, I'd be able to wire things directly into the container right there, and thereby delete a ton of factories from my code, that only exist because at app start, I'm not sure what will be needed.  But that seems odd.  It also means I'd have to recreate my container, or a second container, with each iteration, which seems very strange.

EDIT: I just found out StructureMap has a nested container feature for almost this exact use case, so I'm definitely on to something here: http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/nested-containers/

EDIT: I didn't get any responses, but was able to later answer this anyway.  Added my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is a relatively common scenario.

The first step was recognizing that a lot of my confusion came from the fact that my application is being refactored to, but does not yet have, a clear pub / sub architecture.

Once that is done, it becomes pretty obvious that the code that runs pre and post database could really be seen as separate applications.

At that point, I have basically two choices.  I can treat them as separate apps, in which case they each get their own independent di root.

Or, alternatively, I can continue sharing code between them, and use nested containers.

Apparently most IoCs (I checked Unity, StructureMap and WindsorCastle) have ways where you can pass a parent Container/Configuration object to the sub project, and have it clone and override specific registrations while within that project's scope.

So my initial project can configure database and logging connections, etc, and then each of the sub project instances can extend that shared configuration instance according to whatever data it gets back from the database call.

It also turns out  that the IoC I've been using, SimpleInjector, has no way of doing this.  Hency part of my confusion.